# Find if an array is empty in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP, which I have to check if it is empty.

```
    $length = count($array_new);
    if(empty($array_new)) 
        echo("Array is empty");
    else
        echo("Array is not empty");
    echo("\n");
    print_r($array_new);
    echo("Length of array is".$length);
```

**The output is-**

```
Array is not empty
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
    [3] =>
)
Length of array is 4
```

I know that the array is empty, then why does it show that the length of the array is 4? Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: I guess, array is not empty, but it has values for each index as empty or null. Its big diffrence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your array is not empty, you have assigned 4 keys without value.

```
empty($array_new)    // false
empty($array_new[0]) // true
```

To remove empty values from array use:

```
$filtered = array_filter($array_new, function ($var) {
    return !is_null($var);
});
```

Documentation:

- [empty()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)
- [array_filter()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Thank you for the response - `array_filter($array_new, "isset")` gave me an error. Instead I used this - `$filtered = array_filter($serieNumber_array, function($var){return !is_null($var);} );`

Comment: @SMG Sorry, I forgot that `isset()` is not a function but language construct.

Answer (score 2):

Your arrays are not empty, they just have empty values assigned to those indexes.

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php:

> **The following things are considered to be empty:**
>
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> **array() (an empty array)**
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Currently your array is the equivalent to `array(null, null, null, null);`

Answer (score 0):

You have not empty array with 4 null values. `empty($array)` returns `true` when length of array is 0.